# thermostat assembly verification for electric oven (with pictures)

Tags: thermostat, oven, stove

I am diagnosing issue with my electric oven which does not engage heat element.

Basically it's thermostat (BA, BR, C) -> relays -> heat elements (2 top, 1 bottom). hardwired.

I disassemble the thermostat and want to confirm if assembly is correct for anyone that is familiar with these types of thermostats.

When I disassemble the thermostat the parts imploded due to spring release and didn't have enough time to view.

So I put back together based on best possible configuration, and came up with the following (pictures below).

However, I notice there is always continuity at the leads regardless of whether it's pressed or depressed.

Which doesn't seem right to me.
Should thermostat always be under load?

You can see two springs, when the knob is turned/pushed forward it pushes the bracket which is supposed to engage the contacts/leads at the black part of the box.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Does this look about correct to you?

Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: if the switch stays closed no matter what you do, then it is not correctly assembled

Comment: jsotla, correct. i fixed the issue before by flipping over the bracket that hinges on the springs. now it open and closes correctly. i should probably update the answer now that im here.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the issue by flipping over the bracket that hinges on the springs. now it open and closes correctly.

when it's correctly inserted there is a kind of "clicking" noise and the bracket moves with far less restrain.

basically it's the same as show in the pictures, the bracket with the "circle" indent in the middle needs to be flipped over. the springs then attach the same way.